# Slurm Python script with MPI4py Fail with GPU nodes

Tags: python, gpu, mpi, slurm, mpi4py

I am experiencing errors in scripts that perform MPI assisted computing over python. The error I receive is, unfortunately, fairly generic and uninformative, from my searches

One script yields an error of:

```
g05:rank3.python: Failed to modify UD QP to INIT on mlx5_3: Operation not permitted
```

**Another outputs:**

An ORTE daemon has unexpectedly failed after launch and before
communicating back to mpirun. This could be caused by a number
of factors, including an inability to create a connection back
to mpirun due to a lack of common network interfaces and/or no
route found between them. Please check network connectivity
(including firewalls and network routing requirements).

The slurm script loads the libraries

```
ml CuPy/12.3.0-foss-2023a-CUDA-12.1.1 PyTorch/2.1.2-foss-2023a-CUDA-12.1.1 
matplotlib/3.7.2-gfbf-2023a mpi4py/3.1.4-gompi-2023a
```

And is then followed by a mpiexec python command. The python scripts performs collective communication, and there is a variant with blocking and a variant with nonblocking, and the errors appear the same.

There are no issues, however, when I run the same scripts but without using GPUs and replacing CuPy and NumPy

The sysadmin and I tried different combinations of specific gpu nodes as well as library combinations, but ultimately were unsuccessful in resolving the issue, all suggestions are welcome

Thank you

Comment: As you said, this a fairly generic error unfortunately. But I would start by confirming certain things work on the cluster.
First, write a minimal MPI+Cuda program, maybe just sending a variable around processes and do a basic gpu calculation.
Run it on a different machine if possible, run it single process, run it multi-process, single node, run it multi-process multi node. See if you can reproduce the error with a different code (would mean it is a cluster error). If yes, post the minimal code here.